# Why isn't my transition working when I close my navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make my navigation transition the width from 0% to 20% when you click the 'hamburger' icon. It works when I open the navigation, but not when I close it.

Here is some of the CSS

```
    .nav-toggle.active + nav {
width: 20%;
transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
visibility:visible;
}

nav {
  height: 2em;
  width: 0%;
  line-height: 2em;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 5%; 
  top: 4.5%;
  background: rgba(144, 198, 149, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I've also tried the same thing without the 'visibility' property.

Here is the http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wawRYX with the hamburger icon, for more of a visual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nav` only transitioned when it had the class `.active`, when you removed the class, you removed the transition. `<nav>` must have a transition in its style:

```
nav {
  height: 2em;
  width: 0%;
  line-height: 2em;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 5%; 
  top: 4.5%;
  background: rgba(144, 198, 149, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqKeeO)

Comment: LOL :D glad i could help. Be sure to add vendor prefixes so it workis in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it was only transitioning when `.active` class was applied was because you only had the transition applied to the nav and nav bar when `.active` was applied. Add the transition property to both nav and the nav bar so that the transition will happen with and without the `.active` class.

Here is an [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPbEEL).